# \d1\ Alternative to print a date on documents rather than have the user enter manually?

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending \s1\ perfectly fine to Docusign however \d1\ requests the signer to enter a date manually. This is obviously open to abuse on legal contracts.

Is there another tag i can use that prints the date of signing so the signer does not have to enter a date?

THank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the **Anchor Tagging** feature since I see you referencing strings like \s1\ and \d1\?  Or are you are using the DfS (DocuSign for Salesforce) integration and setting those strings through there?

The bottom line is that yes, it is definitely possible (and easy) to add a date tag that automatically populates based on the date your recipients are signing the document, so that they can not set whatever date they want.  You just need to make sure you are using the `Date Signed` DocuSign tab instead of a regular date tab.

This is what it looks like in the DocuSign tagger:

[image]

If you do not have access to the tagging screen then you'll need to ask your DocuSign Admin.

Comment: I am using anchor tagging however I should have explained in better detail. 
My workflow is,
WebMerge (where the template sits and is generated) 
Docusign (receives request from WebMerge and sends to client)
Because of this, I don't actually use the docusign tagged interface. I just know from reading WebMerge help documents they suggest using \d1\ - \s1\ but also say there are plenty more of these tags but fall short in listing them. 
With this in mind, is there anything as simple as \date\ or Equivalent that I can put in my document template in WebMerge that docusign will understand?